# Revoke YouTube / Google linked permission

Tags: youtube, google-account, security, permissions

I linked my YouTube / Google account to a website and want to revoke that. I am looking into https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions but the service I linked the account at isn't listed there.

I am definitely sure that there is still API access to my account. How can I revoke this?

Answer (score 2):

https://myaccount.google.com/permissions is the new URL.

That's everything that Google knows is linked to your account. If the site you're seeking isn't listed there, then either you're mistaken, they're connecting via a third-party, or you've actually given the site your password and they're accessing it via login and not OAuth.

It couldn't hurt to change your password in any case.